# Get label from a stacklayout with a Tap Gesture Recognizer

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to know what is the best way to get different label from a stacklayout with a tap gesture. My Stacklayout is a part of a grid.

Seems a good idea but doesn't help to get for example the Text value of my brand name.

Heres the content of my stacklayout:

```
Image PictureProduct = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
PictureProduct.Source = FileImageSource.FromUri(...);
Label BrandName = new Label {Text = "HelloWorld"};
Label Description = new Label { Text = "Hello darkness my old friends..."};
Label Price = new Label { Text = "14,99€"};

StackLayout TheStack = new StackLayout { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, HeightRequest = 425 };

TheStack.Children.Add(PictureProduct);
TheStack.Children.Add(BrandName);
TheStack.Children.Add(Description);
TheStack.Children.Add(Price);

var MyTapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();

MyTapGesture.Tapped += (sender, e) =>
{

    Debug.Write(/*BrandName of product*/);

};
TheStack.GestureRecognizers.Add(MyTapGesture);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution who's working for the moment.

```
            StackLayout TheStack = new StackLayout { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, HeightRequest = 425, ClassId = ListProduct[CurrentProd].Sku.ToString(), ClassId = "Something" };

            TheStack.Children.Add(PictureProduct);
            TheStack.Children.Add(BrandName);
            TheStack.Children.Add(Description);
            TheStack.Children.Add(Price);

            var MyTapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            MyTapGesture.Tapped += (sender, e) =>
            {
                StackLayout TappedStackId = sender as StackLayout;
                Debug.Write("TappedStackId = " + TappedStackId.ClassId);
            };
            TheStack.GestureRecognizers.Add(MyTapGesture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not attach the TGR to StackLayout, but to every Label. Then, "sender" should say to you which is the "sender"...

You can try something like

```
PictureProduct.GestureRecognizers.Add(MyTapGesture);

MyTapGesture.Tapped += (sender, e) =>
{

    if(sender is PictureProduct){}

};
```

otherwise, create one TGR for every label

```
PictureProduct.GestureRecognizers.Add(PictureProductTGR);
```

Comment: Seems a good idea but doesn't help to get for example the Text value of my brand name.

Heres the content of my stacklayout:

Image PictureProduct = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
PictureProduct.Source = FileImageSource.FromUri(...);
Label BrandName = new Label {Text = "HelloWorld"};
Label Description = new Label { Text = "Hello darkness my old friends..."};
Label Price = new Label { Text = "14,99€"};

Comment: For a Label something like "var text = ((Label)sender).Text;